# Loop regression: creating interaction term, storing results, pulling out only significant ones

Tags: r, loops, regression, interaction

I have a data set

```
auto <- read.csv("http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Auto.csv")
```

in which I am trying to look for any interaction terms that are significant. I want regressions that only include a single interaction plus its constituting terms (i.e. cylinders + acceleration + cylinders:acceleration is one regression that I want to check).

So far, using other Stackoverflow questions, I have been able to come up with this:

```
results <- NULL
vars=colnames(auto)[-c(1,9)]
for(i in vars){
for(j in vars){
if(i ! = j){
factor=paste(i,j,sep='*')}
for(k in 1:20){
results[[k]]<-summary(lm(paste("mpg~", factor), data=auto)))
}}}
```

However, this continually produces a list with only the last interaction stored inside of it (i.e. the coefficients for origins*year). I would also be ok if the code didn't do only unique values, but also squared versions of the terms. However, since two of them (the final two in the list, origin and year), do not merit squaring, and since I don't know how to have separate lengths for i and j and make it work, I have left that out.

What should I do to get the results that I want from this loop? Should I be going about it a different way? I have also tried to create all the interactions and then append that to the dataframe and run a loop through it, but it doesn't seem to be any more efficient/possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `k` loop has no other effect other than storing the result into a list of length 20. All the values will be identical and what you'll be left with is the summary of the last combination of `i*j`. I would pre-calculate the combinations, create a list for each and feed that to a single loop.

Note that there is a `mtcars` dataset already shipped with R.

```
vars <- colnames(mtcars)[-1]

# Prepare combinations of variables.
combos <- combn(vars, 2, simplify = FALSE)
combos <- sapply(combos, FUN = paste, collapse = "*")

# For each combination, create a formula object and use it in the regression.
# It would be prudent to include the data object into function argument.
results <- lapply(combos, FUN = function(x) {
  frm <- as.formula(paste("mpg ~ ", x))
  summary(lm(frm, data = mtcars))
})

# Rename results names for pretty purposes.
names(results) <- combos

> results[1]
$`cyl*disp`

Call:
lm(formula = frm, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.0809 -1.6054 -0.2948  1.0546  5.7981 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 49.037212   5.004636   9.798 1.51e-10 ***
cyl         -3.405244   0.840189  -4.053 0.000365 ***
disp        -0.145526   0.040002  -3.638 0.001099 ** 
cyl:disp     0.015854   0.004948   3.204 0.003369 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.66 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8241,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8052 
F-statistic: 43.72 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 1.078e-10
```

Comment: This was just what I needed! Thank you so much. I also added this at the end to print the results that I needed for the assignment, which required to identify the significant interaction terms:



`names(results) <- combos
for(i in combos){
  ifelse(results[[i]][["coefficients"]][16]<=.05,print(paste(i, "is a significant interaction")),print(paste(i, "is not a significant interaction")))
}`



Just a question: would the loop I have had have worked better if I had put the object results outside of the loop and assigned the loop output to it, as you have with the lapply?

Comment: @BenWest Your loop was for the last part fundamentally flawed. Also, you would probably have to define "better", I guess.